# Custom Field Formula for MSP

Tags: ms-project, planning

If( [Text1] And [Text4] > 0, [Text1] - [Text4], "" )

I need a syntax for Null/Empty cells in [Text1] and [Text4] to avoid #ERROR

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will skip non-numeric values in the Text fields:

`IIf(IsNumeric([Text1]) And IsNumeric([Text4]),[Text1]-[Text4],"")`

Normally, numeric values are stored in number fields (e.g. Number1, Number4), which eliminates the need to validate the inputs.

p.s. If your custom formula is in a Number field, change the last argument of the IIf function to 0 instead of "".